# Issue executing remote program using WMI Win32_Process

Tags: c#, wmi, win32-process

I do not receive any errors, the program simply does not execute remotely and I am looking for ideas as to why that may be occurring. The program runs fine locally when I run it from the remote computer using command prompt. The program itself takes 10 arguments, hence args[0] through [9] below. Any suggestions are appreciated.

NOTE: I tested this code using notepad and it worked fine, so it seems to be related to how I am calling my program with arguments (as notepad has no arguments).

Thanks

```
String programArgs = @"C:\Report\Report.exe " + "\"" + args[0] + "\"" + " " + args[1] 
      + " " + args[2] + " " + args[3] + " " + args[4] + " " + args[5] + " " + args[6] 
      + " " + "\"" + args[7] + "\"" + " " + args[8] + " " + args[9];

object[] theProcessToRun = { programArgs, @"C:\Report" };

ManagementScope wmiScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + hostname + @"\root\cimv2");
wmiScope.Options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
wmiScope.Connect();
using (ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass(wmiScope, 
                           new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions()))
{
    managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun);
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the value of `programArgs`?

Comment: .. surprised you can run notepad as _"For security reasons the Win32_Process.Create method cannot be used to start an interactive process remotely."_

Comment: Notepad didn't start interactively I don't need it to as my program should run in the background only.

Comment: I added the args array to the example. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you've got the escaping right on the share name? Shouldn't it be `"\\\\server1\\db$"`?

Comment: Also you're getting double quotes round the date - with the change above it looks like `C:\Report\Report.exe "Share" "tiny 3" No Yes No No Yes ""3/13/2018 11:51:00 AM"" mainTable \\server1\db$`

Comment: Sorry I copied and pasted I forgot the "@" before the last argument. I added it in. Still an issue though. The raw command line to my program is below.

report.exe "share" tiny3 No Yes No No Yes "3/13/2018 11:51:00 AM" mainTable \\server1\db$

Comment: ok so I was able to get the program to run on the remote system. and it is running as the correct user. I have a new issue, but I will create anew question for that. Thanks